# Recursive Function NOT Defined When Calling a Method

Tags: python, recursion

I've been chipping away at a problem for a while and am just unsure why the code has an issue. I tried to give the function within the robot class below a self but calling the python files from the command line keeps telling me that the "name generate" is not defined.

The program previously worked before I made it command line-friendly. This line is giving me issues
**for item in generate(remainder_of_list):**

`````
##DRIVER CODE!!!####
from robot import point
from robot import robot
import sys

#Input the argv elements
#The elements go into the robot, who travels the maze
sys.argv
coordinates = point(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]), int(sys.argv[4]))
searcher = robot(coordinates)
one_solution = searcher.find_solutions()
all_solutions = robot.generate(searcher, one_solution)

#Navigate through the solution list
#Because each solution is contained within a list, each list within must be turned into a string
for i in range(len(all_solutions)):
    for w in all_solutions[i]:
        temp_print_out += w
    print(temp_print_out)
    temp_print_out = ""
print("Number of paths: " + str(len(all_solutions)))
print(end='\n')```

###CLASSES CODE!!! DIFFERENT .PY FILE####
class point:
        def __init__(self, beginning_x, beginning_y, ending_x, ending_y):
            self.starting_x = beginning_x
            self.starting_y = beginning_y
            self.final_x = ending_x
            self.final_y = ending_y

class robot:
    def __init__(self, point):
        self.starting_x = point.starting_x
        self.starting_y = point.starting_y
        self.final_x = point.final_x
        self.final_y = point.final_y
        self.all_solutions = []

    def find_solutions(self):
        #, x, y, goal_x, goal_y
        #navigator_x = x
        #navigator_y = y
        #displacement_x = goal_x - x
        #displacement_y = goal_y - y

        displacement_x = self.final_x - self.starting_x
        displacement_y = self.final_y - self.starting_y
        travel_x = abs(displacement_x)
        travel_y = abs(displacement_y)
        is_north = False
        is_south = False
        is_west = False
        is_east = False
        temp_solution = []
        solutions = []
    
        #Abs value the displacement to allow the for loops to do their jobs
        #The N/S/E/W directions are determined by the bools

        if(displacement_x > 0):
            is_north = True

        if(displacement_x < 0):
            is_south = True

        if(displacement_y > 0):
            is_east = True

        if(displacement_y < 0):
            is_west = True

        #If i > 0, then add N, S otherwise
        #If w > 0, add E, otherwise W
        for i in(range(travel_x)):
            if(is_north == True):
                temp_solution.append('N')
            elif(is_south == True):
                temp_solution.append('S')

        for w in(range(travel_y)):
            if(is_east == True):
                temp_solution.append('E')
            elif(is_west == True):
                temp_solution.append('W')
        return temp_solution
        #Recursively find the permutations

        #Use a permutation function to find all possible combos (only 2 directions are legal anyway)
    #Permutation approach to generating all answers
    def generate(self, list):
        #Permutation approach to generating legal answers
        if len(list) == 0:
            return []
        if len(list) == 1:
            return [list]
        #temp_storage = []
 
        for list_index in range(len(list)):
           temp_item = list[list_index]
           remainder_of_list = list[:list_index] + list[list_index + 1:]

           #Recursive approach to generating all legal answers
           for item in generate(remainder_of_list):
               #DO NOT ALLOW DUPLICATES...inefficient method but quicker...
               if ([temp_item] + item) not in all_solutions:
                    all_solutions.append([temp_item] + item)
        return self.all_solutions````
`````

Comment: `generate` is a method on the class, it should be available on `self`, try `for item in self.generate(...):`

Comment: Also not that it is hindering you specifically here, but you should not name a variable `list` as that is a built-in Python keyword (class/type). So your argument to your generate method should be named something different like `lst` or `list1` or something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Line `101` should be:

```
for item in self.generate(remainder_of_list):
```

All methods must be called with reference to the instance or class (`self`)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm a pretty big amateur at Python, so I often need help with these things.

Comment: @小苹果 No worries